# Are locks required when accessing global data that will not be changed?

Tags: multithreading

I am extremely confused about when to use locks when reading data in multi threaded code. I understand if you are reading global data and changing it this requires a lock from the thread that is changing the data. But what if the threads are just reading the data and not making any changes? Are locks required in this case too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're doing is writing the data once (like at startup), and from that point on you'll ever only be reading it, then you don't need to lock. Reading data doesn't change it or cause conflicts in any way.

But, if there's a chance the data will be modified while there are active readers, you'll have to prevent that by locking, or otherwise a reader could read some half-modified data (ie. garbled data) because a writer may be modifying it at the same time.

You can use better mechanisms than plain locks for this situation. One example is reader/writer locks. These kind of objects let you acquire a *read lock* or a *write lock*. It allows multiple simultaneous readers to read the data at the same time by acquiring read locks. But when you acquire a write lock, any other attempt to acquire a lock (be it a read lock or a write lock) will block until the writer is done and the lock is released. This ensures data consistency while allowing parallel readers.

Comment: So in the case for the second paragraph do I need to lock on each data read or only the data reads where I am modifying data? Thank you for the information on the read / write lock I will have to check those out.

Comment: If there's a chance you may be reading and modifying the data at the same time, then yes, you need locks on reads **and** writes. I forgot to mention that if the data is simple enough (like just an int), you could use *interlocked* operations too, which are atomic and don't require locking even when reading and writing at the same time. But this is just FYI, I don't want to confuse you with that, since these are more difficult to get right. So just stay with the basics (locks) at this point until you're confident enough. Concurrency is easy to get wrong, keep that in mind and go the safe way.

Comment: My code when I am done writing it will have a few writes and many reads. I think I am going to use the read / write lock you were talking about in paragraph 3.